# I can't login to server2008 r2 by user that have delegate control

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

I can't login to server2008 r2 by user that have delegate control.
i have to user delegete control (create , delete , manage user accounts) but when want login to server get error " you cannot log on because the logon method uou are using is not allowed on this computer.please see your network administrator for more information".
domain is :test.com
please help me?

Answer (score -1):

You can use MMC to perform create, delete and manage user accounts tasks. If you want this account to be able to log in on the server, you can put this account into the Domain Admins group.

Comment: if put this account into Domain Admins group,why use from delegate?he has full access.

Comment: He has full access on the account objects in Active Directory, not on the actual machine represented by such an account object

Comment: The user doesn't need to be a Domain administrator to be able to log on to the server. The user only needs the appropriate user rights to be able to log on to the server (allow logon locally).

Comment: I agree with joeqwerty, and if this is a Dc too, thus you need to give more permission, logon through terminal server

Comment: Just like I said, you can use MMC to perform these tasks. If you don't want this account to be Domain Admins, you can allow this account to be able to do Remote Desktop.